# C#: How to draw very large controls in a scrollable, zoomable panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, panel

Imagine a bar graph with horizontal bars that may be very wide. I have a Panel on a Form where I want to display these bars and scroll and zoom them. The Form, and thus the Panel, can be resized. The bars are dynamically created from a database. Each time the user zooms in or out, all bars have to be created anew to adjust their sizes on the Panel.

I use Label controls to create these bars, but the problem applies to all other controls as well: If I zoom in far enough, my bars will eventually exceed the magic 16 bit border of control sizes (>65536 pixels). This makes it impossible to simply create all the controls on the panel at start and let the panel handle the scrolling.

My idea: Clear the Panel of all bar controls and create only the ones that are visible in the current view window, according to the current position of the scroll bars and the zoom level. The bars exceeding far from the visible view will be cut short just outside the Panel, so their maximum size is limited by the Panel size.

My questions:

- At which Panel event(s) should this clear/create process take place best?
  There could be thousands of controls, so it should be as seldom as possible.
- Is there a better way to handle this? Maybe I got it all wrong from the start.

This problem arises not only with huge controls but also when smaller controls are very far apart (>65536 pixels) on a Panel, so I think a good solution may be helpful for many projects.

Comment: Are the bars just for viewing or do you need to do something with them?

Comment: Yes, winforms is mandatory.
Yes, the bars should react to mouse events.

Comment: Is this a school assignment(homework) because in winforms this will be extremly difficult, the maximum location for a control is set at 32767.  That alone is going to give you a headache, everything will have to use custom controls. and zooming is very difficult in winforms because of fonts, do you need to zoom any text? or is it just labels with background colors set?

Comment: No, it's not a homework. Maybe I can let go off the winforms usage, but I would like to avoid the (to me) unknown waters of WPF, if this would be your solution. The text itself can stay the same size; the bars are really just a bunch of Labels with text, border and background colour. You know the Gantt charts of MS Project et al? Think of a bar resembling a project that lasts for years and you want to zoom into the second scale. BTW, zooming is only affecting the x-axis here.

Comment: I am just starting to wade into wpf, and when it comes to user interface it is the only way to go.  There is a control called a viewbox, which will automatically size its contents to whatever size it is, what that means is, if it is 200 pixels large, everything inside will be scaled to fit, if its 2000 pixels everything is scaled to match.  So what I do is I put it inside a scrollable panel, and make it the size I want the zoom at.  Maybe this is a little too brief but I can only say so much in a comment. what you are suggesting is possible, it will be slow and choppy

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't like to have to create / destroy controls, or hide / resize controls just for their click events. It's quite easy to create a `UserControl` and override the `OnPaint` method to draw the bars, and override the `OnClick` or `OnMouseXxx` events.

Since you already know the positions of the bars in "virtual space", it's easy to map the location of the mouse cursor to a bar (or a click outside a bar).

Comment: I completely second this one, since you'll have much more luck with creating a user control and responding to OnPaint, and drawing the bars yourself with Graphics object.

Comment: Let's see if I get you right: I should just create the Panel and draw my bars with Graphics functions. In the event routines of this Panel I should check which bar the user is over from my database.
Where is the advantage of this? Better performance?

Comment: I don't know what role the database has in this (no difference from when you used labels); the advantage isn't just performance, in my opinion it also makes more sense that if you want to display a custom sized bar, you draw a bar, not add a label control meant to display text only. And you'll rid of the 65536 limit which caused you to post the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said winforms is Mandatory, but I really think you should look into the wpf viewbox. You can host a wpf element in winforms.  So everything else can be forms related, and you have a panel that hosts and displays your controls.  I could write up a quick example that might demonstrate this for you, but if you have no intent of going this way I really don't want to waste my time.

Comment: Looking at the Viewbox, I learn that it does a good job of stretching its contents. Unfortunately, this is not what I intend. The bar's text should remain the same size and the border should not grow. It's really not a literal, pixel-wise zoom but more a logical one.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a metafile (vector graphics), show that in an image control, and manually determine which logical element is clicked.