# How to draw zoomable picturebox without redrawing new points

Tags: c#, drawing, zooming, picturebox

i have read : [C#: How to draw very large controls in a scrollable, zoomable panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813283/c-how-to-draw-very-large-controls-in-a-scrollable-zoomable-panel)

in my problem, i'm using picturebox to draw my chart(actually it's a contour) in c#. i want to draw picturebox that can be zoom like zedgraph(c# library) when i scroll my mouse :

[image: 1]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

my question is : can i draw it without recalculate the point and draw it from the start like zedgraph do?

Comment: At some point you're going to have to anti-alias this. Otherwise, what you could do is make sure you limit your viewport when re-drawing, thereby saving some CPU cycles.

Comment: so basically there is no way i can zoom it without recalculate n redraw all my point(in my viewport)?

Comment: You can.. its just the more you zoom.. the blurrier it will be. This is what I meant by anti-aliasing, which will smooth the lines. Otherwise, you can cache a couple of zoom levels up to a point, then start re-drawing if the user zooms further.

Comment: yeah, that's what i want to avoid, my image become blurrier, :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends a little bit on what your graph/contour looks like.
But, I think yes, you could draw the whole contour once at full zoom, and the change the width/scale/x attributes to manipulate the display when zooming and panning.

Comment: @Ardhian'koponk'Nugroho yeah so to clarify, what I mean is that if you calculate your points once at "full zoom" you should be able to keep using that without recalculating your points ever again. For example, you want to display your contour within a box thats 800px; then you might draw the contour at full zoom at something like 5000px ... and then when you zoom in and out, you just fit more of the contour image into the 800px box.

Comment: @Ardhian'koponk'Nugroho do you have any code of getting your contour into your picturebox?

Comment: my friend suggest that too, maybe i should try it.

yes, i'm using paint event handler in picturebox to draw my point(to draw my contour, i'm using some algorithm which draw rectangles from a rectangle that i construct from 4 point in my grid data)